# SC.exe causes Access Denied

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-services, jenkins

I am calling the following commands from machine A to machine B.

```
<Exec Command="net.exe use \\B /delete" IgnoreExitCode="true"></Exec>
<Exec Command="net.exe use \\B /user:B\<username> <password>" IgnoreExitCode="true"></Exec>
<Exec Command="sc.exe \\B stop <service name>" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

The first two commands work fine, but the last one results in an Access Denied erorr.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the account under which you are running the script does not have the required privileges to stop services. See [Services permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782435%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does `<username>` have access to control the service on B?

Service entries have ACLs too, normally only administrators have control access, but this can be changed. This can include blocking local administrators from stopping a service.

Comment: <username> is an administrator on B.

Comment: @Sachin See last sentence: that *might* not be enough.

Comment: Hi Richard, the server B, is a new build.  I've added the Windows services to it and I've installed everything on it that it has on it.  So I certainly have not restricted services from being started by administrators.  How does one check and modify the ACL of services anyway?  Also, one thing I've noticed is that when I go onto B and run these commands from there in a command window it fails but if I open a command window in Administrator mode it passes.

Comment: @Sachin The service ACL can be set via Group Policy (so joining a domain would be enough). There are tools around (eg. `SVCACLS.EXE` from the resource kit) that will show these ACLs.